# adding file to project causes build issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

This might be simple operation.. but this is my first time working with a big solution file and adding files to a project

I have a class library project(say a user control library) within that is a part of a bigger solution with (about 100+ project) all of this is connected to TFS. As soon as I add a class file to the project, it checks out the project file and the file gets added, but then I notice a maximum number of errors exceed and that project build errors start showing up.

This might a real simple thing I am missing, but what is the best way to resolve this issue.

The issue I get is a lot of 
- 'namesspace x 'not a member of 'y'
- Type namespace x' is not define. 
x namesspace cannot be converted to y namespace.

and eventually, maximum number of errors exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple answer is to fix your namespaces or add the missing projects/references.  Generally speaking the error you are talking about is due to the code not being able to locate certain dependencies - such as other class files.

This typically happens when you haven't added all of the relevant projects and/or references.